The introduction of tuples in the python official website is different from the actual application
`A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective. For example:
>>> singleton = 'hello',    # <-- note trailing comma
>>> len(empty)
0
>>> len(singleton)
1
>>> singleton
('hello',)

The statement t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!' is an example of tuple packing: the values 12345, 54321 and 'hello!' are packed together in a tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:
>>>
>>> x, y, z = t

This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires that there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as there are elements in the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.
This is the original text
If I write this in pycharm
t=(123456,654321,'hello')
print(t)

result is
(123456, 654321, 'hello')

but if i write
(123456,654321,'hello')=t
print(t)

is wrong
I don’t know if there is a problem with my understanding of the original text or a problem with my actual operation or a problem with the software.`

What were you expecting (123456,654321,'hello')=t to do?  You could do something like (a, b, c) = t to unpack the elements of t into separate variables - but what you tried would attempt to assign those values to constants, which is simply meaningless.

The language is working fine. This is just not what tuple unpacking does. The left side should be a series of variables you want to change, and the right side should be a preexisting tuple. (123456,654321,'hello') is not a series of variables.

Assignment is not symmetric. The target is always on the left, and (123456,654321,'hello') is not a valid target.

Didn't you get a syntax error on that last one?

Always post your errors

You can't unpack a tuple (or a list for that matter) in to literals - when unpacking a tuple/list, you provide a series of variables to take the values of the corresponding elements in it. That's why your second example fails.

Is [], [] = [], [] not unpacking in to literals?

Notice in the example x, y, z = t, those are variables on the left hand side. When you wrote (123456,654321,'hello')=t, those are literal values. When tested, you get a syntax error
>>> t=(123456,654321,'hello')
>>> (123456,654321,'hello')=t
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (123456,654321,'hello')=t
     ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal

Its the same as if you had written
1 = 2

which is obviously wrong for everybody except Terrence Howard. Python does not let you assign to literal values.
If you mix variables and literals, python will highlight the first invalid assignment, but will not do a partial unpack.
>>> (foo, bar, 'hello')=t
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (foo, bar, 'hello')=t
               ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
>>> foo, bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

